# Even after validation failed the new page is redirected

Tags: javascript, html, validation, jsp

I am implementing a simple code just to figure out why validation is not working in my browser.

But validation is not working. Idk y.

It is just redirecting to next page

**newjsp.jsp**

```
  <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script>
        function validation()
        {
            var a=document.form1.txt1.value;
            if(a=="")
            {
                alert("Hey");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" onsubmit="return validation(this)" action="newjsp1.jsp">  
    <input type="text" id="txt1">
    <input type="submit" id="sub">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Do not use `this` as a function parameter. `this` is a keyword. Use any other variable. Something like this

```
function validation(form) { 
  var a=form.txt1.value; 
  if(a==="") { 
    window.alert("Hey"); 
    return false; 
  } 
  return true; 
}
```

When the form is like this

```
<form name="form1" onsubmit="return validation(this)" action="newjsp1.jsp">
....
</form>
```

---

Try `document.forms.form1.txt1.value;`

```
function validation(){
  var a=document.forms.form1.txt1.value;
  if(a==""){
     alert("Hey");
     return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Check the demo **http://jsbin.com/vuxoha/1/edit**

Comment: nah...Still no change

Comment: Validation has failed so it should not redirect to new page right?..it is..and there is no alert window

Comment: try placing the script below the form. Looks like script is not executed at all

Comment: <body>
        <form id="form1" onSubmit="return validation(this)" action="newjsp1.jsp">  
            <input type="text" id="txt1">
            <input type="submit" id="sub">
        </form>
        <script>
            function validation(this)
            {
                var a=document.form.form1.txt1.value;
                if(a==="")
                {
                    window.alert("Hey");
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        </script> 
    </body>..

Comment: you have a typo, it should be `document.forms.form1.txt1.value ` and not `document.form.form1.txt1.value `

Comment: Noooo...still nothing

Comment: btw, you cannot use `this` as a function parameter variable `function validation(this){} ` use another variable, any other variable. `this` is a keyword which is causing the issue

Answer (score 0):

Use opposite logic - something must be OK, then turn TRUE, in all other cases, return FALSE.

```
function validation()
{
  var a = document.getElementById('txt1').value;
  if (typeof a != "undefined" && a != "")
  {
    // `a` is in very good condition :)
    return true;
  }

  alert('hey');
  return false;
}
```

I think, your `document.form1.txt1.value` is not filled correctly, so your value `a` is probably undefined and not "", so it will return TRUE.

Try to debug with `console.log(a);`

And finally, use `var a = document.getElementById('txt1').value;`, just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of form id use name

```
<script>
        function validation()
        {
            var a=document.form1.txt1.value;
            console.log(a);
            if(a=='')
            {
                alert("Hey");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>    
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" onsubmit="return validation(this)" action="newjsp1.jsp">  
    <input type="text" id="txt1">
    <input type="submit" id="sub">
  </form>
</body>
```